# Simple Query intermittently returning 0 results

Tags: mysql, innodb, select, amazon-rds

I'm having a strange problem and need help troubleshooting.

if I run this query on my gallery table:

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     `gallery` 
WHERE    awarded = 1 
ORDER BY awarded_date DESC LIMIT 29 OFFSET 0
```

it works perfectly, but then randomly return 0 results, for a few seconds and then continues working.

I could be wrong but i think i have narrowed the problem down to the 'awarded' column, as other queries of the same database seem to work without this issue.

the awarded column is an int with value 1 or 0

any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: I have fixed the issue by deleting the Index on the awarded column. don't understand the problem but at least it's over.

Comment: How many records in the table?

Comment: Would be worth editing the question to include the results of `EXPLAIN <query>`, including when the problem occurs if that differs, details of the table (size, what ratio of rows will be awarded) and any indexes defined on it, in case the problem is something weirder than suggested in my answer. Also, when you see the issues is the database seeing an increase in concurrent access?

Answer (score 1):

Improve the situation by adding a composite index:

```
INDEX(awarded, awarded_date)
```

Is there some other process that is doing bulk changes to `awarded`?  Perhaps not transaction-safe?

Answer (score 1):

As you are only returning 29 rows, it is most likely that at the times nothing is returned a bunch of rows not matching `awarded = 1` have been entered so it *should* be returning nothing, and afterwards some rows matching `awarded = 1` arrive and things go back to as you expect.

Another possibility is that the rows are being build up in bits without transaction protection, so are being inserted with `awarded = 0` then a short time later updated so `awarded = 1`, but without being wrapped in a transaction¹ so it sees the partial result despite the updates being in an as yet incomplete transaction. This would mean that for a time those rows could be seen before the flag is set to `1`. If the issue is transaction (or lack there-of) based timing matter, you will notice this more during times of high activity as the affected inserts/updates/other will take longer to complete meaning the window of time when the values are not yet correct is longer.

A third reason why you might see zero despite rows of both types being continuously inserted depends on what indexes are/n't being used. You might think that the rows are going in mixed together but those matching `awarded = 1` could be more bunched together in the data pages than you expect so 60 rows, 30 with it set to 1 and 30 set to 0, are inserted but are not stored intermingled but in bunches decided by the flag. This is not unlikely if you have an index on just `awarded_date` and the date values are *just* dates not dates+times, and even more likely if you have an index on `awarded_date` (and those are just dates) *and* `awarded` together as the 0s will be before the 1s for any given date. If you don't specify a sort order, the DB engine is free to sort things³ as it sees most efficient, or just arbitrarily if it sees no efficiency difference either way.

<sub>1: or with your query being run with an isolation level like `READ_UNCOMMITTED`²</sub>

<sub>2: see [these docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html) as a staring point for information on isolation levels if you are unfamiliar</sub>

<sub>3: both when storing the rows in data/index pages, and when presenting them as requested by a query</sub>